# My wife has died

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

In 1980, a man lives on the 30th floor of his building. Every morning he wakes up, gets ready, kisses his wife, takes the elevator down to the first floor, and goes to work.

One morning, he wakes up, gets ready, kisses his wife, and gets in the elevator, exactly as he always has done. The morning is exactly the same as any other morning, and no one else was in their apartment.

The man is alone in the elevator and there are no windows in or visible from the elevator. Without receiving any  communication of any kind, or the man being in any danger of any harm, he begins crying when the elevator reaches the 12th floor, because he knows his wife has died.

How is this possible?

Notes (added later) to eliminate "too broad" answers:

> His wife was alive when he left the apartment.
>  The man loved his wife, and would never harm her in any way.

And for the more extreme options:

> The man had a boring typical day job. No danger involved. 
>  The laws of physics have not been repealed, and there are no mythical or fiction occurrences happening.
>  As always, aliens are not involved.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't really work - death would not follow instantly. The husband would have prepared by [taking some of the steps listed here](http://www.srpnet.com/prices/medical.aspx#prepare) and [here](https://www.synergy.net.au/at_home/life_support.xhtml).

Comment: @AE Today, you're probably right. I believe this puzzle is older than cell phone ubiquity, though, or at least I heard a variant of it years ago. A battery backup seems likely, though most "home" units have(or had) a short life span, more useful for flickering than total loss.

Comment: @AE Does the edit address your concern?

Comment: @Geobits, yeah, it seems unlikely that she be allowed at home if death followed instantly from that not-awfully-unlikely event. Incidentally, here in the UK, [fixed line phones continue to operate if that thing happens](http://consumers.ofcom.org.uk/phone/problems-and-complaints/landlines-and-power-cuts/), though that may be totally different in other countries of course.

Comment: @AggieKidd, 'fraid not. Cellphone not the main issue. Main issue is that death would not be immediate, and that this kind of event is not particularly unexpected or unusual (e.g. see links above) so it's something the husband would have prepared for.

Comment: @AE How about now?

Comment: @AE I agree it's unlikely, but so are many things I've seen in the lateral-thinking tag. Who has infinite rope laying around? Death doesn't need to be immediate, though. If he is stuck in an elevator with no phone (and she can't reach a fixed line), then no help is coming for her any time soon. Even if he assumed he was prepared, he wouldn't expect to be stuck without a phone somewhere nearby.

Comment: @Geobits He uses his portal gun to place a portal in the side of the elevator, linked to the ones he has already placed in his wife's bedroom and at the nearest hospital. ;) (But remember, the question states she's already dead when he reaches the 12th floor - "going to die if nothing else happens" isn't the situation as stated).

Comment: OK, it [does](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/greece/10987521/Greek-quadriplegic-woman-on-life-support-dies-due-to-unpaid-power-bills.html) [happen](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jul/15/two-men-die-after-perth-tornado-cuts-power-to-home), although probably not that quickly.

Comment: "My wife died, better make a post on Stack Exchange" - typical Stack Exchange user

Comment: I'm confused.  Are we supposed to know whether the wife was still alive when he left her and entered the elevator?  Otherwise I'm just going to assume that his wife was already dead (and possibly that he killed her).

Comment: He always takes off her oxygen mask to kiss her.  When he reaches the 12th floor in the elevator he notices the oxygen mask is still in his hand.  Oops.

Comment: The wife has been long dead. Maybe a week, perhaps a year or more. He is lonely and keeps her body around for company. He gives her corpose a kiss every morning, and cries in the elevator on the way downstairs, generally around half-way down to the ground floor.

Comment: @adamp I'd upvote that as an answer. It's creepy as hell, but it seems to fit the question well.

Comment: Naah, his wife was fine yesterday. The thing is, he steps out of bed every day and gets ready, but he's not really awake, doing everything on automatic pilot, until the coffee kicks in. This happens about halfway down on the elevator and only then does he realise today how cold and pale and stiff his wife was when he kissed her.

Comment: upvoted this question because I like the *other* answer so much.

Comment: This question always bothered me a bit because it's not exactly logical to assume that she was on in-home life support without any sort of battery backup on the 30th floor of a building and having been able to survive for some time without any sort of power outage happening before,  _in the 80's_. It is a interesting question, of course, but it's less lateral-thinking and more "jump-of-faith thinking" than anything else. Usually good puzzles kinda lend themselves well to Occam's Razor. This one... not so much. The answer depends on too many assumptions to work.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

His wife

> is on in-home life support.

The elevator

> stops at the 12th floor because the power in the building went out.

So now he's

> stuck in an elevator (despite being in no harm) while his wife is dying upstairs.

I guess you could argue that the event is a sort of "communication", but that seems pretty weak to me.

Comment: Dang, I thought this would last at least an hour. Nice job!

Comment: I have a problem with this--life support equipment without battery backup???

Comment: @LorenPechtel See comments on OP for my take on this.

Comment: @Geobits While most home battery backups are simply for orderly shutdown life support equipment is another matter--the reality is the power does go out at times, you're going to have some beefy batteries and you very well might have a generator besides.

Comment: @LorenPechtel In today's world, I completely agree. I don't know enough about the state of life support equipment in 1980 to say that for certain. I doubt your statement holds true for every life support machine in the world, though.

Comment: This is certainly the answer I've heard to this classic puzzle but it's always bothered me that the man assumed the elevator losing power meant the whole building lost power.

Comment: Power going out IS a communication signal.  My version is that he temporarily removes the life support (e.g. oxygen mask) from her face every morning in order to kiss her.  In this instance, he realized on the 12th floor that he's still holding her oxygen mask in his hand.  Oops.

Comment: The battery running out could work if he was stuck on the 12th floor without power for over an hour (or however long the batteries were supposed to last).

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: pahaha I lol'd. oops.

Comment: @LorenPechtel The man probably realised he forgot to replace the backup after the last power cut.

Comment: The man was heading to buy replacement batteries, her current ones were dead.

Comment: "The morning is exactly the same as any other morning" - so did the power in the building cut out every morning as the guy reaches the 12th floor?

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I assumed it meant up to that point (as he gets in the elevator) it was the same. That's the same assumption that led me to believe he doesn't start crying because his wife dies every day also.

Comment: @Geobits, actually that works as an answer. He cries every day because he knows every day that his wife is dead. The 12th floor just reminds him of her because ... (insert personal connection with the number 12 here).

Answer (score 95):

I know I'm coming in late here, however, I'll toss a completely different take on this.

> When he kisses his "wife" each morning, it's only a picture. She died a year ago on this day. He's crying because it's the 1 year anniversary of her death.

Comment: 12th floor reminds him of 12 months - math checks out

Comment: Or 12 year anniversary.

Comment: Or, she's a corpse, dead for quite awhile.  He's been keeping her around out of love and denial.  One day, on the way down the elevator, he cracks emotionally and breaks down, finally coming to the realization that his lady is deceased.  The 12th floor happened to be the floor he was at the moment he realized, nothing significant about the floor or the timing.

Answer (score 47):

My solution:

> The building he lives in has a 13th floor.
>
> However, this morning he noticed the 13th was missing, it went from the 14th floor directly to the 12th floor. 
>
> The only possibility? The labyrinth builder was superstitious of the number 13 so his copy of the building did not include it.
>
> The man is Dom Cobb, and he is in a dream. His wife, Mal Cobb, committed suicide years ago. The error in the building has made him aware of the dream.

Inception!

Comment: Inceptus Nolanus overratus.

Comment: this is the definition of thinking outside the box

Comment: Username checks out.

Answer (score 36):

Maybe

> He poisoned her morning coffee.

Comment: I doubt he'd be crying then.

Comment: @AE Does your wife know you make posts like this on SE? :-o

Comment: @pacoverflow: Depends on _why_ he poisoned her.  If he did it in her best interest, he might be crying.  It was my first guess.

Comment: @pacoverflow: You've never heard of rash decisions? And ensuing guilt? It's _extremely_ naive to simply assume that, having executed this act (no pun intended), he could only possibly be happy about it in the aftermath.

Comment: the man does the same thing every morning, does that mean he poisoned her morning coffee everyday?

Comment: How would he know she was dead by the time he reached floor 12? What if she hadn't drunk it? What if she had been dead by floor 16? What if she didn't die until he reached floor 8?

Comment: @Vic - The morning itself is exactly the same as any other morning (sunny with a chance of showers), it's the man's actions that differ. Although he does all the things exactly as he always has done, he also does an extra thing (the poisoning).

Comment: @Pharap, he watched her drink it, and the time it took him to reach the 12th floor was the longest time she could possibly have lived given the dose of poison. She *might* have died earlier but by the 12th floor he *knew* she was definitely dead.

Comment: @AE Its also possible that the man knows enough about medicine that he could give her the same dose of poison each day and know that today would be the lethal dose.

Comment: @pacoverflow - As Lightness says, tears of guilt. His feelings are complex, he's not just a one-dimensional character you know. ;)

Comment: @acbabis Exactly! A very valid possibility.

Comment: The problem states that `The morning is exactly the same as any other morning`, if the man does an extra thing then it is no longer the same as any other morning

Comment: @Vic, I'm playing on the ambiguity of "the morning" in the text you quote. Could refer to the man's actions (your interpretation) but I'm choosing to interpret it as referring to the morning itself, ie the nature of the morning itself - warm and sunny perhaps - rather than the man's actions during the morning. It's pedantry, I know. ;)

Comment: @Vic To be fair, the accepted answer technically fails that test too, because if the power is out, that is something that makes the morning different too.

Answer (score 25):

The husband and wife have been living under assumed names, on the run from the CIAfia and in possession of a briefcase containing documents of earth-shattering significance. It's absolutely clear that if the CIAfia find where they're holed up, they won't engage in negotiation: they'll just kill them and make off with the documents.

The couple's problem is that they've lost contact with the agency they're supposed to hand the briefcase to. They fear their usual contact has come to harm. All they can do is wait and hope that someone else in the agency knows the procedures for making contact. Husbie nips out every morning to check for the chalk mark. He always uses the proper tradecraft, so it takes him about 3 hours. And when he gets back, he always checks on exiting the lift that his wife has put a flowerpot in the pre-arranged place. If she hasn't, that will only mean one thing: she's dead and the CIAfia have taken the briefcase. In that event, he's offski: he'll turn sharp left, pay no more attention to the front door of the flat, and walk down the stairway to floor 29.

Leaving is as tense as arriving. The guys looking for them aren't gunslinging cowboys. Nobody's chances are ever 100% in this game. If they can, they'll improve their odds by entering the flat when the wife's alone. But they won't waste time. After all, when the husband goes out, the opposition could in principle make contact with him within a minute or so and he'll lead them straight up to the flat. So if possible the CIAfia will go in and kill his wife and take the briefcase as soon as he's gone out, when he's been in the lift for only a few seconds.

So every morning, she texts him. She listens for the lift door opening and closing and then she sends a text within 15 seconds. She's a professional; she doesn't forget. If she doesn't send the text, there's only one possible meaning - she's dead.

He's a professional too, but that doesn't mean he's not scared. He was trained to control his fear. He looks calmly at his watch. Five seconds. Ten seconds. By the time the lift reaches floor 12, thirty seconds have elapsed. They've killed her. Cry a tear. The CIAfia have got the documents. On to the next stage.

(*He **didn't receive the communication**. That's the point. Let's say the man's not in danger, because the only reason the CIAfia would kill whoever's looking after the briefcase at the moment of collection is to prevent harm coming to the documents.*)

Comment: This is all nice, but everyone knows you can't get any signal inside an elevator.

Comment: Heh nice writing, and you worked into it a loophole of sorts, quite nicely.

Comment: A bit more long winded than necessary, but a reasonable solution nonetheless.

Comment: Very nice story, but... He didn't receive text message, but he did communicate nevertheless. This was a form of digital signal. He did *receive* 0 at the end.

Comment: Remember the riddle takes place in the 1980's so no text messages, but this is now my go-to answer for any modern interpretations of the same riddle.

Comment: @Ennar - Point taken, but the information-theoretic usage of *receive communication* would be highly unusual in ordinary non-technical English.

Answer (score 16):

Possibly

> His wife is ill and needs a certain medication daily at exactly the same time. On this day, the man forgot to give her the medication and remembered once he saw the number 12 in the elevator. Perhaps 12 is involved in her dosage.

Comment: Good thoughts, but no. The man does everything exactly the same way this morning as he does every other morning, meaning if the wife needs medication, he would have given it to her.

Comment: Some more good thoughts, but if a man is good enough to follow the same routine every morning, then any medication would have run out long before it expired.

Comment: Plausible and somewhat related to the 'actual' answer.

Answer (score 9):

My solution is that

> Early every morning, the man's wife wakes up, puts coffee in the coffee pot, prepares their lunches for the day, and then goes back to bed for a couple hours. Today, she passed away in her sleep briefly before her spouse awoke. Her body was still warm when he kissed her.
>
> The man got hungry in the elevator and discovered that his lunchbox was empty. Because his wife had been recently diagnosed with a terminal illness, it was reasonable to believe that she had died rather than slept-in.

Comment: Please could you add some explanation as to why you think this answer fits the question as stated? Answers without explanation (even witty ones!) often get downvoted and even deleted here.

Comment: @randal'thor Was your criticism that I hadn't explained why the lunchbox was empty or that I didn't explain how she died? I don't think I need to explain how she died.

Comment: My criticism was that you hadn't explained why you think this is the correct answer to the question. You still haven't: why is it "natural" that he presumed the worst? The OP says he "kisses his wife, and gets in the elevator, exactly as he always has done." (I wasn't the downvoter btw.)

Comment: Struggling not to downvote this. The question says that he 'knows' she's dead, not that he presumes her to be dead.

Comment: @Pharap If you disagree with it, then you should downvote.

Comment: -1 If his wife was supposed to be making coffee as well as the lunch, the husband would notice his morning coffee wasn't ready. And in a pre-emptive rebuttal, it would be silly to make yourself coffee and then go back to bed.

Comment: @Pharap My mother-in-law makes herself coffee and then goes back to bed; no joke

Comment: @acbabis I'm still going to stand by my -1. Even if you take the coffee out of the equation, the man is presuming she is dead rather than knowing definitively.

Answer (score 6):

The 18-story power cord from his wife's life support system popped out of the DC-AC power converter attached to the car battery in his back pack and he began to cry. Obviously.

Comment: That would be funny if it weren't so sad.

Comment: @Pharap This answer is even less serious than the question. The pretty impossible logistics are a dead giveaway.

Comment: @Pharap I see what you did there.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe

> The wife committed pre-planned suicide due to a lengthy agonizing illness.  She didn't want him there.  By the time the elevator got to the 12th floor he knew she was dead.

Answer (score 3):

Their building was old, with an elevator entry protected by a rather flimsy metal grille that's not hard to push aside even when the elevator isn't there.

The wife suffered from chronic depression and would occasionally threaten to kill herself by jumping into the elevator shaft.

That morning, she did it.

---

Another variation of the same idea: their apartment was on the top floor, near the electrical hub for the building, which (again because the building was old and poorly maintained) was easily accessible.

The wife had depression and would threaten to kill herself by electrocuting herself through direct contact with the high voltage (5000V) transformer. That morning, she did it. This caused power in the building to go out; the elevator stopped, and the husband understood the reason why it was happening (because of the wife's constant suicide threats) and started to cry.

Answer (score 2):

When he left he had set up the bomb, and when he reached the 12th floor he heard, or felt the shockwave of the explosion.

The wife's name was Old Yeller in this interpretation.

Comment: He did everything the same--no bomb.

Comment: I'd +1 for the bomb, but the man setting the bomb up himself is a bit convoluted.

Comment: @LorenPechtel All the things that he did (getting up etc), he did in the same way as usual (e.g. got out the same side of the bed, showered for the same number of minutes), but we don't know that he didn't do an extra thing.

Comment: Perhaps he set up the bomb the night before, so that morning he did everything as usual. The bomb would be triggered by the elevator reaching the 12th floor.

Comment: @Kevin: OK, so he sets up Schrödinger's bomb every morning of 1980, exactly the same way every day (barring hidden variable theories), with a 1/366 chance of going off, and today's the (first) day it did. I grant you, I can't pierce the mind of someone that peculiar to determine whether or not he'd cry...

Comment: All her base belong to him, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

It is not specified that it is modern day, or present Earth.

It is also not specified if his realization came on his way home or on his way to work.

In the older days, elevators had an elevator operator. His wife was normally the operator, for the time that he got home from work and rode the elevator up. She was not there that day to give him the ride up, even though she was very loyal to her job. It took him until the 12th floor to reason out every other possibility of why she wouldn't be there.

Alternately, at the 12th floor there's a restaurant, and she met him there for dinner every evening, when he got home... she was not there to greet him when the doors opened on the 12th floor.

Comment: (I mention present day / modern earth, both to qualify the elevator operator, and to qualify it being a woman, as that was very uncommon)

Answer (score 2):

> Perhaps they had a pact: every day after he kissed her goodbye and got in the elevator, she would run down the stairs to the 12th floor (getting there ahead of the elevator) and press the button to summon it. Then it would stop at the 12th floor, the doors would open, she would give him a kiss and run back upstairs again while he continued on his journey to work. She had told him that she was suicidally depressed and if she ever failed to do this ritual, it would mean that she had taken her own life. So when the elevator got to the 12th floor and failed to stop, he knew she had died.

Answer (score 0):

> The elevator had glass walls. Upon reaching the 12th floor, he saw his wife's body fall past...

Comment: "there are no windows in or visible from the elevator" so it couldn't have windows. Glass walls is a nice loophole though.

Answer (score -1):

He has an affair with a woman. He plans to kill his wife. Poisoned her food and went. But felt repentant in the elevator as it is stuck due to power failure.